# All my windows drivers have gone down

Tags: windows-10, drivers

Only the trivial features of Windows 10 are working. For e.g. my touchpad sidescroll function gone, can't change display brightness, my speakers no more working on high bass settings, my phone when connected in usb debugging mode gets an error to install adb drivers, the power button feature set by me to turn off the display is gone, moreover the taskbar search is not working. Its my dad's PC and he says it all has happened because I changed his wallpaper which he had been using since 2015. So I cannot (even knowingly) accept the fact that windows has become corrupt. I want a solution apart from reinstalling Windows please. Also driver update is of no help

Comment: Restore from your last backup.

Comment: How did you change the background? What things were done to the computer before the issues occurred? Also, don't change things on computers that aren't yours, even things as simple as the desktop background.

Comment: Did you try system restore?

Comment: @music2myear Nothing big but I opened the BOOT advanced options earlier today in SysConfig for testing a code I wrote on a single core. But later I changed it to default values.

Comment: You broke it. You should use a virtual machine or purchase your own computer for testing code. Messing about in SysConfig is NOT changing the background, and it has big implications. Your only option is to Restore or Reinstall.

Comment: The bad news is that my dad never created a restore point in his PC ever, so system restore would remove all his apps and programs which did not come with windows.

Comment: Try running  **msconfig** and make sure it says **Normal Startup**

Comment: @cybernard Yes msconfig worked!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try msconfig first
  Make sure it says **Normal Startup**

IF my previous suggestion fails:

1. Backup everything up as it is now (do not skip)
2. download [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
3. Run tool
4. Make to select **Keep all programs and settings**
5. Complete and in place upgrade.

Comment: Thank You so much man. You saved me from getting grounded for the next one week.

Comment: @ManasSingh   I added msconfig to the answer so you can mark it as the answer.  You are welcome. Now convince your parents to do backups and restore points.  Also I suggest you install virtualbox so you can have a virtual OS you can break without risking the rest of the computer.